# Check for Dev cert. expiry programmatically

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to build a utility (preferably within the app.) to check and notify if the Dev Cert. used to sign the application is going to expire soon.
I have been doing some research into this but did not find anything concrete for this. So, my questions:

- Is it possible to do it within the app?
- If it is not possible within the app, can make a web based or any
  other tool that does the same?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Once an app is released to the App Store, it is signed by Apple and never expires. The expiration of the developer signing certificate is of no consequence to the continued operation of the app.  The situation is different for enterprise signed apps.

Comment: It is more like for development/ maintenance purpose - making it a part of say... the integration tests within the app. So that, the team gets notified about upcoming expiration rather than someone going to the portal and notifying everyone.

Comment: Then it makes more sense to put it in your CI process than in the app itself. I haven't looked into it but I would imagine that the OpenSSL command line tools could extract the expiration date from the certificate. You could then have your CI issue a warning or a failure based on how close the certificate is to expiring.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am investigating on that front too. However, wanted to know if this app based approach is an option or not.

Comment: I don't believe that the app itself has any visibility of its signing status